# Rewrite the Views from existing data access layer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nuget-package

I'm ready to reboot my web app's views into a brand spanking new, rigorously testing, sharply razored view spewing machine. There's tons of learning curve embedded in my legacy pages and i'm better off just walking away from it and starting from scratch with the canonical stack of jQuery1.4/jUI/MVC3.

The question is how to most easily migrate my existing back-end (based on Unity and nHibernate, the facades are of passible quality so it should be a fairly clean decoupling) - should i be looking at any other strategy or resource [besides mvcScafolling as this recent post?](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/)

Any bit of advice on how to make the process most productive? anything i can do (or hire to have done) the enhances how well the code gen part can best pick up my data structures?

REFINEMENT>>

If working with a back-end that contains the same conceptual structures (customer, product, cart) - just different names.

Wouldn't bolting the Music Store FE (as distributed with mvc3) be a feasible way to meld or merge in a fairly robust front end (musicstore) to my data?

Comment: `brand spanking new, rigorously testing, sharply razored view spewing machine` : loooooooooooooooool +1 for this sentence. I will try to remember it. That's poetry.